# Apache Camel Split by start and end characters SOH and ETX

Tags: regex, split, apache-camel, tokenize, spring-camel

I have an spring boot application which have routes.xml being loaded on startup

On the routes.xml, i have a MQ queue source that contains sample message

```
SOH{123}{345}{4
5
6
}ETXSOH{111}{222}{3
3
3
}ETX
```

where SOH = \u0001 and ETX = \u0003

When i receive this message, i want to split the message to two

```
{123}{345}{4
5
6
}
```

and

```
{111}{222}{3
3
3
}
```

Currently i am trying to split using

```
<split>
  <tokenize token="(?s)(?&lt;=\u0001)(.*?)(?=\u0003)" regex="true"/>
  <to uri="jms:queue:TEST.OUT.Q" />
</split>
```

I have tested this regex using online regex tester and it was matching.
https://regex101.com/r/fU5VVj/1

But when runnning the code what i am geting is
#1

```
SOH
```

#2

```
ETXSOH
```

#3

```
ETX
```

Also tried the token and endToken but not working for my case

```
<tokenize token="\u0001" endToken="\u0003" />
```

Is my case possible using camel route xml? If yes, can you point me to correct regex or start and end token.

Thanks

Comment: Try `token="(?&lt;=\u0001)([^\u0001\u0003]*)(?=\u0003)"` or just ``token="\u0001([^\u0001\u0003]*)\u0003"``

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew using (?&lt;=\u0001)([^\u0001\u0003]*)(?=\u0003) i am getting the same results, while using \u0001([^\u0001\u0003]*)\u0003 i am getting empty strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems camel regex is different with java regex, just created a new process using sample code below

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?s)(?<=\\u0001).*?(?=\\u0003)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(items);
    List<String> tokens = new LinkedList<>();

    while (m.find()) {
        String token = m.group();
        System.out.println("item = "+token);
        tokens.add(token);
    }
```